# Which form is correct? Listen on/with/ through/in your headphones? (for instance music)

Tags: grammar

Which  form is correct? Listen on/with/ through/  your headphones? Have you ever used IN ?

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=listen+with+headphones%2C+listen+through+headphones%2C+listen+on+headphones%2C+listen+in+headphones&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clisten%20with%20headphones%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clisten%20through%20headphones%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clisten%20on%20headphones%3B%2Cc0) shows equal usage of with/through/on but nothing for 'in'.

Comment: Can you post a complete sentence with your desired usage?

Comment: Please listen to the rocording on your headphones. (in class)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **in headphones** to refer to a group of people and how they are dressed. For example: By the time I got to the room they were all *in headphones*.  Some white, some black, some with wires, others not. They were listening to my lecture of the previous day, or so they later claimed.

Comment: Although your example of 'in headphones' may be technically possible, it does not sound natural and would be generally rejected by a native speaker, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, I’m a native speaker, and to me this doesn’t sound out of line. **In headphones** is equivalent to **wearing headphones**. You can use **in** with quite a range of wearables.

Comment: I agree that in can be used with a range of wearables, "in jeans", "in pajamas", "in hats", etc. But I think it is a stretch to use it for functional devices like headphones - to me it sounds quite unnatural.  Would you also say that "in watches" is ok? I wouldn't. Perhaps it's a matter of opinion, but I certainly wouldn't recommend this usage to a student of English.

Comment: It’s a stretch, I agree. For a student of English, maybe something to understand in reading or listening, but not to actually use. The expression with *in* draws attention to the wearable. Perhaps *in watches* is going too far, but *decked out in Rolexes* might not be.

Answer (score 0):

Listen on/with/ through/ your headphones are all fine. 'in headphones' is unnatural